# Spring -batch Process all the records parallelly using threadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring-batch, threadpoolexecutor

I am using **threadPoolTaskExecutor** with below configuration in `Spring Batch` application.

```
<bean id="threadPoolTaskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="15"/>
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="30"/>
    </bean>
```

Also  processing records in chunk  with `commit-interval="20000"`.

```
<batch:tasklet  task-executor="threadPoolTaskExecutor">
            <batch:chunk reader="inputItemReader" writer="itemWriter"
                commit-interval="20000" skip-limit="10000">
            </batch:chunk>
</batch:tasklet>
```

I am processing of file with 200k records, what i am observing is

It starts 4 thread each of picking 20000 records to process. Once all the 4 threads process the records then next again 4 threads will be created to process remaining records. I am not understanding why it is creating only 4 threads  and waiting to complete.

I want to process all the records `parallelly`, .i.e it should create  more than 4 threads (may be 10 threads) and process all  parallely.

what is missing here?

Comment: The default throttle limit is 4 (you can set that on the tasklet) which means it will at most start 4 threads at a time (or process using 4 threads at a time). Increase this if you want more concurrent processing.

Comment: Please try to avoid using words like *lac* that are not globally understood.

Comment: @M.Deinum- I tried to add throttle-limit="15" as below in my tasklet but still same issue.


<batch:tasklet  task-executor="threadPoolTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="15">
            <batch:chunk reader="inputItemReader" writer="itemWriter"
                commit-interval="20000" skip-limit="10000">
            </batch:chunk>
</batch:tasklet>

Comment: If you increase the throttle limit, you should see more threads processing data concurrently. If this is not the case, please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue and I will try to dig deeper.